# using regular expression to split string with multiple spaces.

Tags: python, regex, findall

I'm trying to split a string that is delimited by multiple spaces 
i.e:

```
    string1 = "abcd    efgh   a. abcd   b efgh"
    print re.findall(r"[\w.]+")
```

as expected, the results are:

```
    ['abcd', 'efgh', 'a.', 'abcd', 'b', 'efgh']
```

However, I would like to group 'a.' and 'abcd' into the same group, and 'b' and 'efgh' into the same group. So the result I want would look something like:

```
    ['abcd', 'efgh', 'a. abcd', 'b efgh']
```

My approach at the moment is to create two types of expression. The first to deal with the regular expression without the space i.e. 'abcd' and 'efgh'. The second to deal with the ones with a single space. i.e. 'a.' + 'abcd'.

So if
        r'[\w]+ 
can deal with the first type, and 
        r'[\w]+ [\w]+ 
can deal with the second type. But I don't know how to combine them into the same expression using '|'.

As always, any other approaches are welcome. And thanks for your time!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
result = [s.strip() for s in string1.split('  ') if s.strip()]
```

i.e. splitting on *two* spaces and removing extraneous spaces from the result (using strip).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use `re.findall`, you can use this expression:

```
>>> string1 = "abcd    efgh   a. abcd   b efgh"
>>> print re.findall(r"\S+(?:\s\S+)*", string1)
['abcd', 'efgh', 'a. abcd', 'b efgh']
```

`(?:\S+(?:\s\S+)*)` finds a non space character followed by a single space and more non-space characters multiple times if they exist, so that this works too:

```
>>> string1 = "abcd    efgh   a. abcd   b efgh ijkl"
>>> print re.findall(r"\S+(?:\s\S+)*", string1)
['abcd', 'efgh', 'a. abcd', 'b efgh ijkl']
```

Otherwise, it's much simpler to use split by more than 2 spaces:

```
>>> string1 = "abcd    efgh   a. abcd   b efgh ijkl"
>>> print re.split(r"\s{2,}", string1)
['abcd', 'efgh', 'a. abcd', 'b efgh ijkl']
```

Comment: Why not only ``re.findall("\S+(?:\s\S+)*")`` ? Also, rawing the string is completely useless here, since all the backslashes are intented to be interpreted as metacharacters by the re compilator, not simple backslashes characters.

Comment: @eyquem Because `re.findall()` accepts between 2 to 3 arguments? Did you try running `re.findall("\S+(?:\s\S+)*")`? If I do , I get an error. And using the raw string is a habit just so errors are avoided when backslashes need to be interpreted otherwise.

Comment: I evidently forgot to write the second argument: ``re.findall("\S+(?:\s\S+)*",string1)``

Comment: @eyquem, ALL python regexes should employ raw strings, period. Experts use raw strings at all times for regexes because they've been bitten enough times to know better. Beginners don't use raw strings because they don't know any better.  When you see a regex that uses raw strings and the flags 'xms' that is a good indication the programmer is not a beginner.  Jerry- the non-capturing group around the whole regex doesn't do anything.  Non-capturing groups are used when you need to modify the whole group with a quantifier but you don't need to capture the group.

Comment: @7stud I actually had a quantifier sometime between writing the first regex and actually posting it here xD Thanks for pointing it out. I appreciate the support, though I might disagree about using all the flags like that xD. I reached my vote limit today, but I'd balance your downvote once I get them back. Not sure why your answer was downvoted...

Comment: Hey Jerry, About the flags--perl is sort of the center of the universe when it comes to regexes, and in perl advanced regex users turn off the 'bad' aspects of regexes by always specifying the 'xms' flags by default.  It's just like the r"" convention in python--you just do it as a reflex.  It doesn't matter whether it actually affects the current regex or not.  Maintenance is a consideration with regexes too, and if you always add the r"" and /xms, then the regex will behave the same way no matter what is inside it.

Comment: Forget about the downvote, I deleted my answer because after I added a more general regex, I compared it to your answer, and the regexes were the same.

Comment: @7stud Oh, okay, I see your point now. Thinking more about it, I don't remember having used `^$` for a whole file. Only thing maybe is using `.*[\r\n]` but that can be substituted by something else easily to behave in the same way.